# Redirect www to non-www with traefik

Tags: traefik

I am using docker-compose to spin up some service and having traefik as reverse proxy. I have correctly configured http to https redirect but the redirect of www to non-www is not working and I am not sure if I am doing anythin wrong. Here down a snippet of the configuration:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "50m"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./data/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik_dashboard.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:somepass"
      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

  myservice:
    image: prestashop/prestashop:1.7
    restart: always
    container_name: "myservice"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "50m"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.rule=Host(`myservice.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice.middlewares=redirect-to-https"

      - "traefik.http.routers.cdn_myservice.rule=Host(`cdn.myservice.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cdn_myservice.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cdn_myservice.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cdn_myservice.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      
      - "traefik.http.routers.www_myservice.rule=Host(`www.myservice.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.www_myservice.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www_myservice-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https?://www\\.myservice\\.com(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www_myservice-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=http://myservice.com$${1}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www_myservice-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.www_myservice.middlewares=www_myservice-redirect"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if it's something wacky with the regex, or with how that's getting passed through to Traefik from Docker – I tried and gave up using `redirectregex`, but I was able to [use `SSLForceHost` fine](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/4138):

```
- "traefik.http.routers.myservice.rule=Host(`myservice.com`, `www.myservice.com`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.myservice.middlewares=${STACK_NAME}-redirect"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.myservice-redirect.headers.SSLForceHost=true"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.myservice-redirect.headers.SSLHost=myservice.com"
```

This combines the redirect onto the main service (i.e. instead of adding it to the `www_myservice`); I personally have a global HTTP → HTTPS redirect set up in `traefik.yml` but I guess it should work OK to have it per-service as you do -- just make sure `SSLForceHost` is on the SSL-enabled one!